# child div position absolute parent height not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Parent div height not working.

**wrap** height not working.i need both child div absolute.and i need css tricks for this.no need jquery.

any one can help me.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="clild"></div>
    <div class="clild2"></div>
</div>


<style>
.wrap{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.clild{
    position:absolute;
    width:450px;
    height:200px;
    background:#069;
}
.clild2{
    position:absolute;
    width:350px;
    height:300px;
    background:#096;
}
</style>
```

Comment: your wrap doesn't have height

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. They are in their own layout context. Therefore they take no space in the parent element.

If you want the parent to have a height, you need to assign one.

Answer (score 0):

you parent div doesn't have height. please replace the .wrap class style to following style:-

```
   .wrap{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        width : 600px;
        height:500px;
        background-color:red;
        margin:0 auto; 
  }
```